# Cancel out of DoWork and fall into RunWorkerCompleted

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a `BackgroundWorker` in a WPF application. If a condition is true, I want to immediately stop processing the `_DoWork` method and go straight to the `_RunWorkerCompleted`.  I'm using `.CancelAsync`, but the code after this point continues to execute.

How can I cancel out of my `_DoWork` and fall into `_RunWorkerCompleted`?

Example:

```
private BackgroundWorker step1 = new BackgroundWorker();

public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    step1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    step1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(step1_DoWork);
    step1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(step1_RunWorkerCompleted);
}

private void step1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        step1.CancelAsync();                
    }
    // code I do not want to execute
}

private void step1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // I want to jump here from the cancel point
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`CancelAsync` is a method designed to be called by something *other than the `DoWork` handler* to indicate that the `DoWork` handler should stop executing.  The `DoWork` handler should be checking to see if the BGW has requested cancellation and if so, stop executing (either by returning, throwing an exception, or otherwise not performing further work).

Comment: Also, don't expect when you call CancelAsync that it'll immediately set the `CancellationPending` to **true**. It's possible that under `RunWorkerCompleted` that `CancellationPending` is still false.

Comment: @lll Sure, that's inherent to asynchronous and multithreaded code.

Answer (score 1):

In your `DoWork` handler, check the cancellation state.

```
private void step1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        step1.CancelAsync();                
    }

    if (!step1.CancellationPending)
    {
        // code I do not want to execute
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

---

```
    private void startAsyncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void cancelAsyncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
        {
            // Cancel the asynchronous operation.
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        }
    }

    // This event handler is where the time-consuming work is done.
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
            }
        }
    }

    // This event handler updates the progress.
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        resultLabel.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
    }

    // This event handler deals with the results of the background operation.
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Canceled!";
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Done!";
        }
    }
}
```

}